# Set a formula only in blanks cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to set a specific formula but only in the blanks cells.
This is the code, I don't need to get "0", I don't need a value: I need a formula!

This is the formula that I want:

```
//formula "codice ditta" colonna D   
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var cell = sheet.getRange('D2:D'+sheet.getLastRow());
 cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(INDEX(CO.Contatti!A:A;MATCH(E2;CO.Contatti!B:B;0)))')
```

This is the code where I would get formula. (not setValues but setFormula...)

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Zeros")
.addItem("Sheet", "zeroSheet")
.addToUi();      
}   
function zeroSheet() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data, range;
var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();    
range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, (lastRow-1), 1);
data = range.getValues();
range.setValues( data.map( function(row) {
return row.map( function(cell) {
return !cell ? 0 : cell;
});
}));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I mostly used your code.

```
function setFormulaInBlankCells() 
{
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getMaxRows();
  var lastColumn=sheet.getMaxColumns();    
  var range=sheet.getRange(2, 4, (lastRow-1), 1);
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if(!data[i][0])
    {
      sheet.getRange(i+1,4).setFormula('=IFERROR(INDEX(CO.Contatti!A:A;MATCH(E2;CO.Contatti!B:B;0)))'); 
     //data[i][0]='=IFERROR(INDEX(CO.Contatti!A:A;MATCH(E2;CO.Contatti!B:B;0)))'; I have actually done this in the past and it will work this way. But your call.
    }
  }
  //range.setValues(data);//If you use commented code you'll need this.  It runs much faster.
}
```

The updated version with cell that updates with the row it's currently on

```
function setFormulaInBlankCells() 
{
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getMaxRows();
  var lastColumn=sheet.getMaxColumns();    
  var range=sheet.getRange('D2:D'+sheet.getLastRow());
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if(!data[i][0])
    {
      var A1=sheet.getRange(i+1,5).getA1Notation();
      var formula='=IFERROR(INDEX(CO.Contatti!A:A;MATCH(' + A1 + ';CO.Contatti!B:B;0)))'
      sheet.getRange(i+1,4).setFormula(formula); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you get the right one. I've been editing it.

Comment: It works but the formula should not be fixed.. This formula contains cell E2 that refers to the second row that is the first row of my range... I want that the number of the row change every row: E2, E3, E4 containing the number of this row where formula is contained!

Comment: Okay I think that's what you need

Comment: I ran the script but I have a problem: blanks cells are D740 to D745 but this code set the formula from D739 to D745...how can I solve?  Other question: can I get only the final value and not the formula? So that I can have better performance..

Comment: The ranges came from your code.  So I ask "What do you want?".  I can't read your mind and I have no access to your data so you must articulate your needs.

Comment: I want that the script set the formula and then It set the values that come from the formula

Comment: The range is the first one. sheet.getRange('D2:D'+sheet.getLastRow());

Comment: What is in D739 before script runs? Perhaps a space?